# Android:Text became blurred after I call canvas.scale()

Tags: android, canvas, scale, blurry

When I want to enlarge my custom view text by using canvas.scale(),the text became blurred,as follows:

```
@override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
super.onDraw(canvas);
canvas.translate(50,50 );
canvas.scale(mDpi/72, mDpi/72);
canvas.drawText("Stackoverflow!", 50, 50, mPaint);
}
```

the mDpi is 320,when it runs in a phone,it is blurred;However,when the code runs in nexus 10,it's normal!Somebody can tell me why?

Answer (score 8):

I have got the solution!

```
private void closeHardwareAcceleration() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
}
```

Because after api 11,view is draw with HardwareAcceleration,just close it!